# Skin modifier not same size on all points

Tags: modifiers

I'm using the skin modifier to make a model but when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> to scale it down it disappears on some points.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Try recalculate normals. Or maybe share the file so we can take a better look.

Comment: Thanks actually i already solved this, there was a duplicate of the point in the same location